# how to return the due date for payment starting at the next month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have built this function that must return me the first payment due date for a pledge based of that pledge id. there is a date for every pledge in my table and the payment happens at the first day of each month,starting from the month following the pledge date.I need to invoke it from anonymous block ...hope it's clear enough...

here is the function code

```
create or replace function DD_PAYDATE1_SF (

pledge_id dd_payment.idpledge%type)

return  date is 

payment_date  dd_payment.paydate%type;

begin 

select    paydate  into payment_date from dd_payment 
where dd_payment.idpledge = pledge_id;



return payment_date;

end  DD_PAYDATE1_SF;
```

I tried the trunc function but it seems to return me all the subsequent payments-as I receive this error when invoking the function "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"-
while I need only the first one of them 
how can I solve it

Comment: The `dd_payment` table can contain a number of past and future payments for a `pledge_id`; and you have another table that has `pledge_id` and `pledge_date` (I'll go out on a limb and guess it's called `pledge`)? Do you want the first payment date after the pledge date, or the next one after today?

Comment: @AlexPoole I need the first payment date after the pledge date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join to the table that has the pledge date (I'm guessing `pledge`), filter to only get payment dates after that, and use the `MIN` aggregate function to get the first date:

```
create or replace function dd_paydate1_sf (
  pledge_id dd_payment.idpledge%type)
return  date is 
  payment_date dd_payment.paydate%type;
begin 
  select min(d.paydate)
  into payment_date
  from pledge p
  join dd_payment d on d.idpledge = p.pledge_id
  and d.paydate > p.pledge_date
  where p.pledge_id = dd_paydate1_sf.pledge_id;

  return payment_date;
end dd_paydate1_sf;
/
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b3c1/1).

Although it's questionable if the join and filter are necessary, as they imply you can have a payment before you pledge, which doesn't really make sense; so you could probably get the same effect just by adding `MIN()` to your original query.

This won't show the first date for a new pledge (one received this month) and will return null. If you wanted those as well, and your rule about the first of the following months is always true, you could ignore the payments table and just work out what it should be:

```
create or replace function dd_paydate1_sf (
  pledge_id dd_payment.idpledge%type)
return  date is 
  payment_date dd_payment.paydate%type;
begin 
  select trunc(p.pledge_date, 'MM') + interval '1' month
  into payment_date
  from pledge p
  where p.pledge_id = dd_paydate1_sf.pledge_id;

  return payment_date;
end dd_paydate1_sf;
/
```

The `TRUNC(<date>, 'MM')` gives you the first day of the month that date is in, and you can then add one to get the first day of the following month.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14de0/1).

It depends if you want the first expected payment date, or the date that a first payment was actually made, assuming `dd_payment` is recording actual payments that have occurred.

---

To get and display one value in an anonymous block:

```
declare
    paydate date;
begin
    paydate := dd_paydate1_sf(104);
    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(paydate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
end;
/
```

Comment: I just don't understand why I get 40 line of repeated value output...I got 01/11/2012 which is the value of the first payment due date but I got 40 line of them????

Comment: @user2396035 - how are you calling the function? You can only get one result back from each call, so are you doing something like `select dd_paydate1_sf(pledge_id) from pledge`? That ought to give you one row per record in the table, though the dates could all be different.

Comment: this is my statement select dd_paydate1_sf(104) from pledge

Comment: where 104 is the pledge id

Comment: @user2396035 -a nd `pledge` has 40 rows, presumably. You're selecting every row from the table (since there is no `where` clause) and calling the function for the same value. You can either do `select dd_paydate1_sf(104) from dual` or `select dd_paydate1_sf(pledge_id) from pledge where pledge_id = 104`, either of which will get one result. You said you were going to invoke it from an anonymous block though?

Comment: yup...but for the time being I wanted to see if it gets me the desired output...because I guess the block is not a big deal...I will do begin followed by DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE  ( dd_paydate1_sf(pledge_id)); am I right dude

Comment: this did the trick buddy                                                               begin 

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( dd_paydate1_sf(104));
end;

Comment: one more thing if I need to use the same function to get me the final payment date..how would I modify it,to get me that final date?

Comment: @user2396035 - you can call it inside the `dbms_output` call, but it's more normal to assign it to a variable; I've added an example of that. You can use `MAX()` instead of `MIN()` to get the last date in the DD table.

Comment: but for pledges  that have only one payment day which is the same day of the pledge date,I got no return date

Comment: @user2396035 - to include the the pledge date use `>= pledge_date`. You said 'the month following' which implied `>` was appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change your select statement.
If you want the first one, you can do the following:

```
select   paydate  
into     payment_date
from 
       (select paydate 
        from   dd_payment 
        where  dd_payment.idpledge = pledge_id
        order  by paydate)
where    rownum = 1;
```

Comment: when I invoke it from SQL statement  select  DD_PAYDATE1_SF(104) from dd_payment; I got a 40 row of output for the same value why is that dude?...in fact I need to invoke it from anonymous block

Comment: That's because you passed a fixed value as a parameter. If you are using the DD_PAYDATE1_SF function in a select statement, surely you would pass the column of a table as the parameter for this function, not a fixed value... Something like: `SELECT DD_PAYDATE1_SF(t.pledge_id) from TABLE t`